# How to write data when setting the local authentication as trust?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

The ticker table is created by the sql:

```
CREATE TABLE ticker(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    ticker  text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I want to insert some string into a simple table in database .

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxxxxx@127.0.0.1/test')
content = 'a string'
insert_str = "INSERT INTO ticker(id,ticker) VALUES (1,{});".format(content)
engine.execute(insert_str)
```

It encounter some error info:

```
File "/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The content in configuration file `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` is as below:

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

The record can be inserted by sql command.

```
su -  postgres
Password: #type xxxxxx
postgres@debian:~$ psql
Pager usage is off.
Border style is 4.
Null display is "(null;)".
psql (13.8 (Debian 13.8-0+deb11u1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c  test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# insert into ticker(id,ticker) values(1,'xxxxxx');
INSERT 0 1
test=#
```

How can fix my python code to insert record?

Comment: Remove `127.0.0.1` so you are connecting as `local` not `host`. As it stands now using SQLAlchemy you are hitting `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5` whereas in the command line example you hit `local   all             postgres                                trust`. FYI, in command line case you can skip the `su -  postgres` and as any user do `psql -d test -U postgres`. The database user `postgres` is different from the OS user `postgres`.

Comment: Also **do not do**: `"INSERT INTO ticker(id,ticker) VALUES (1,{});".format(content)`. See [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for correct and safe way to pass in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Login with super user `postgres` and issue the alter command:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'xxxxxx';
```

Comment: That is an answer to a different question: How do I alter a user password? You where asking how to connect using `local trust`.